# ConnectivityManager ClassCastException with Google Analytics v4 and ProGuard

Tags: android, google-analytics, proguard

I'm having troubles compiling an app that uses ProGuard and Google Analytics v4. A single other thread that seems to be similar is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784281/proguard-avoiding-naming-collisions-with-pre-obfuscated-library-jars), except there aren't very many details.

I've tried the following to no avail:

1. Doing `keep com.google.** { *; }`
2. Doing a `-keep android.support.** { *; }` package. This error continues to crop up with every other bit of obfuscated code, as if joining the newly obfuscated code with the pre-obfuscated Google Analytics code always causes errors.
3. Using `-keepattributes Signature` in case there's an issue with generics.
4. Using an obfuscated dictionary of four-letter words (such as rNqp, sSlq) in case something to do with Android dexing causes the pre-obfuscated Google Analytics classes to conflict with the obfuscated project files.

Here is the exception:

```
11-08 22:45:01.644    2206-2226/com.example.helloworld E/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Error on GAThread: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.ConnectivityManager cannot be cast to android.support.v4.d.a
            at com.google.a.a.a.at.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.a.a.a.am.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.a.a.a.s.h(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.a.a.a.s.g(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.a.a.a.s.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.a.a.a.u.run(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.a.a.a.ab.run(Unknown Source)
11-08 22:45:01.644    2206-2226/com.example.helloworld E/GAV3﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Google Analytics is shutting down.
```

Proguard configuration file (99.9% vanilla):

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

# Optimizations: If you don't want to optimize, use the
# proguard-android.txt configuration file instead of this one, which
# turns off the optimization flags.  Adding optimization introduces
# certain risks, since for example not all optimizations performed by
# ProGuard works on all versions of Dalvik.  The following flags turn
# off various optimizations known to have issues, but the list may not
# be complete or up to date. (The "arithmetic" optimization can be
# used if you are only targeting Android 2.0 or later.)  Make sure you
# test thoroughly if you go this route.
#-optimizations !code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
#-optimizationpasses 5
#-allowaccessmodification
#-dontpreverify

# The remainder of this file is identical to the non-optimized version
# of the Proguard configuration file (except that the other file has
# flags to turn off optimization).

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

-keepattributes Signature
```

Comment: Have you tried to add -keep class com.google.** {*;}

Comment: @Devrim yes, I have. That command will tell ProGuard to not obfuscate all the Google libraries that I'm using in my project. However, the problem doesn't seem to be that the Google libraries are being obfuscated, rather that there is some kind of conflict with the pre-obfuscated Google Analytics library and the newly obfuscated code. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. It just involves not obfuscating the `ConnectivityManager`. I've used:

```
-keep android.net.** { *; }
```

which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using a copy of proguard-android-optimize.txt (a more common approach is to refer to the original, maintained file in the Android SDK). You can try disabling optimization:

```
-dontoptimize
```

If this indeed avoids the problem, you can report the issue in [ProGuard's bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs) or to me directly.

Make sure that you are using the latest version of ProGuard (version 5.1 at this time of writing) and the latest version of the GMS library.

(I am the developer of ProGuard)